# UITableview to cell detail with image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I currently have a UITabelview that displays a list of medications, each connecting to its own scene with its own image view.
Is it possible to connect the UITableview to only one scene and just change the image based on what the user picks within the table?

This is the link to the image to view my storyboards:
https://ibb.co/6FcDySW

Code is also displayed.

```
class MedicationsController: UITableViewController {
    var RXnames = [String] ()
    var RXidentities = [String] ()
    var RXdetail = [String] ()

    @IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        RXnames = ["Acetaminophen", "Activated Charcoal","Adenosine","Albuterol", "Amiodarone", "Aspirin","Atropine Sulfate",
        "Calcium Chloride","Dextrose","Diltiazem","Diphenhydramine","Dopamine","Epinephrine","Etomidate","Fentanyl","Furosemide",
        "Glucagon","Glucose (Oral)","Ibuprofen","Ipratropium Bromide","Ketamine Hydrochloride","Ketoralac","Lidocaine","Lorazepam",
        "Magnesium Sulfate","Methylprednisolone","Metoprolol","Midazolam","Morphine Sulfate","Naloxone","Nitroglycerin",
        "Nitrous Oxide","Norepinephrine","Ondansetron","Oxygen","Promethazine","Racemic Epinephrine","Rocuronium","Sodium Bicarbonate",
        "Succinylcholine","Transexamic Acid","Vecuronium"]

     RXidentities = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
            "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
              "21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30",
            "31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43"]

      RXdetail = ["Tylenol", "CharcoAid","Adenocard","Ventolin", "Cordarone", "Bayer","Atropen",
        "CaCl","D50W","Cardizem","Benadryl","Intropin","Adrenalin","Amidate","Sublimaze","Lasix",
        "Glucagon","Glucose (Oral)","Motrin","Atrovent","Ketalar","Toradol","Lidocaine","Ativan",
        "Mag","Solu-Medrol","Lopressor","Versed","Duramorph","Narcan","Nitrostat",
        "Nitrous","Levophed","Zofran","O2","Phenergan","Rac Epi","Zemuron","Bicarb",
        "Anectine","TXA","Norcuron"]


    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return RXnames.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RXcell")

        cell?.textLabel!.text = RXnames[indexPath.row]

      cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = RXdetail[indexPath.row]


        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      let vcName = RXidentities[indexPath.row]
       let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: (vcName))
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Comment: yes you can change....there are lots of tuts available on internet

Comment: this is very poor way of writing what you would want is to create a model for it and when user tap cell send the model of that index path to the detail view

Comment: any time you find yourself creating an array where the value is the index (or index +1) you should ditch the array and use the index

Comment: Do you know where I can go to find a tutorial? I've searched many times and have been unable to find a suitable result. Im sure im not utilizing the correct terminology for what I'm wanting to accomplish hence why I probably am not finding a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of creating a whole model class, you could do something like this where I've combined your RXDetail and RXNames so as to keep the data together and lessen the chance of errors should you change the order or add/remove items. As requested I have updated this to include an array of images. I hope this helps.

```
class MedicationsController: UITableViewController {

    var RXItems : [(name:String, detail:String, images:[UIImage])]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        RXItems = [("Acetaminophen", "Tylenol", [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "example-image"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "example-image")]),
                   ("Activated Charcoal", "CharcoAid", [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "example-image")])] //etc
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return RXItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RXcell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = RXItems[indexPath.row].name

        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = RXItems[indexPath.row].detail


        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailsSegue", sender: indexPath.row)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "showDetailsSegue") {
            let viewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            viewController.images = RXItems[sender as! Int].images
            viewController.title = RXItems[sender as! Int].name
        }
    }

}
```

It appears you haven't set the delegate correctly in the storyboard, however I have improved my code to both set this in code, and set the size of the images to be constrained to, at most, the width of the root view (`self.view`) whilst maintaining the aspect ratio:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var images : [UIImage]?
    var imageViews = [UIImageView]()
    @IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    private var _contentView : UIView?
    var contentView: UIView {
        if(_contentView == nil) {
            _contentView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(_contentView!)
        }
        return _contentView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        if let images = self.images {
            var contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 0)
            for img in images {
                let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: CGRect.infinite.height)
                let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
                let iv = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0, y:contentSize.height), size: AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: img.size, insideRect: rect).size))
                contentSize.height += iv.frame.size.height
                iv.image = img
                self.contentView.addSubview(iv)
                self.imageViews.append(iv)
            }
            self.contentView.frame.size = contentSize
            self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        var contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 0)
        for iv in self.imageViews {
            let size = CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGRect.infinite.height)
            let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
            iv.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0, y:contentSize.height), size: AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: iv.image!.size, insideRect: rect).size)
            contentSize.height += iv.frame.size.height
        }
        self.contentView.frame.size = contentSize
        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.contentView
    }
}
```

Then set your storyboard up like:
[image: Storyboard layout]

Only replace the UIImageView with a UIScrollView, setting the delegate and outlets accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, again! You're amazing!

Comment: Is there a way I can add two images to one item? When I add one image the code works, but when I add two It errors out.

Comment: @Wesley See my edits. if I understand correctly then it should work for you.

Comment: I can see where in your edits how this works. I have tested it and I am able to implement two images into one screen. The issue I am running into now is the image sizing. While the UIImageView is constrained to the view, the image does not fill approriately. No matter what setting I utilize, (Aspect Fill, Scale to Fill, Aspect Fit, etc.), the image will not resize and is blown up. I cannot find where in your code where I would correct this.,

Comment: This code will set the size of the UIImageViews to the size of the images. There are three options: set the zoom level of the scrollview; call `init(withFrame:)` instead of `init(withImage:)` on the UIImageViews; and finally the preferred option, you can adjust the images themselves to be the size you desire. This will improve the memory taken by the UIImages as the memory footprint is dictated by the dimensions of the image, as opposed to any compression or format the images are saved with.

Comment: My images are full sized PDFs that are not constraining to the view. The UIScrollView is constrained to the edges of the view. Im attaching an image link here (https://ibb.co/DwQJKd4). As you can see, the image is completely zoomed in. Again, thank you so much for your help on this!

Comment: Are you able to zoom in and out? Have you set the minimumZoomScale to a value lower than the default of 1? Have you set the auto layout constraints on the uiscrollview within the storyboard to the edges of the screen (leading, trailing, top and bottom)?

Comment: ThomasHaz - Unless I am mistaken, I have already tried all of that. Ive attached my code and workspace. https://ibb.co/3FcfYHG
https://ibb.co/tKbMB9X

Comment: Within the `viewDidLoad` method after calling super, try adding `self.scrollView.delegate = self`. It sounds like the delegate mightn't have been set in the storyboard correctly. (I'm unable to see in the screenshots you sent)

Comment: As an aside, you should really add a uinavigationcontroller as the initial view controller, then set the UITableViewController as the root view controller of it.

Comment: These are how my delegates are set up. The navcontroller is rooted on the main view. https://ibb.co/RCZ2WM1
https://ibb.co/hZx1JpG

Comment: There is no UINavigationController there; also the delegates you have shown are from the UITableViewController